# How to transform series to columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've input structure:

```
[{"id": 1, "name": "John", "events": [{"date": "2018-10-10", "value": 1}]}, 
 {"id": 2, "name": "Kyle", "events": [{"date": "2018-11-10", "value": 2}]}]
```

After loading to `DataFrame`, events is stored as `Series`. 
I need to convert events series to columns like that:

```
id name 2018-10-10 2018-11-10
1  John 1 0
2  Kyle 0 2
```

how to flatten this structure in pandas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`json_normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html) with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) an [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
L = [{"id": 1, "name": "John", "events": [{"date": "2018-10-10", "value": 1}]}, 
     {"id": 2, "name": "Kyle", "events": [{"date": "2018-11-10", "value": 2}]}]

from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

df = json_normalize(L, 'events', ['id','name'])
df = (df.set_index(['id','name','date'])['value']
        .unstack(fill_value=0)
        .reset_index()
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
print (df)
   id  name  2018-10-10  2018-11-10
0   1  John           1           0
1   2  Kyle           0           2
```